# PDE: How to solve this equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Solve $$2xu_x-2yu_y+u_{x}^2 +u_{y}^2 = u$$ with
>   $u(x,0)=1-2x^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Here is what I tried. Setting $p = u_{x}$, $q = u_{y}$ yields

$$F(x,y,z,p,q)=2xp-2yq+p^2+q^2-z=0$$

The initial data is $\Gamma: ( x=f(s)=s, y=g(s)=0, z=h(s)=1-2s^{\frac{1}{2}} )$ when $t=0$

The characteristic equations are

\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= F_p = 2x+2p \\
\frac{dy}{dt} &= F_q = -2y+2q \\ 
\frac{dz}{dt} &= pF_p+qF_q = p(2x+2p)+q(-2y+2q)=z+p^2+q^2 \\
\frac{dp}{dt} &= -p \\
\frac{dq}{dt} &= 3q
\end{align}

Now I find initial condition for $p$ and $q$. Let $p=\Phi(s)$ and $q=\Psi(s)$

We have

\begin{align}
h'(s_0) &= \Phi(s_0)f'(s_0) + \Psi(s_0)q'(s_0) \\
\implies -s^{\frac{-1}{2}} &= \Phi(s_0) \\
\implies p_0 &= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}
\end{align}

From this point, I stuck. Please help. Thanks

Comment: If your ODEs are correct, then $p$ and $q$ can be solved for explicitly from the equations for $p'$ and $q'$. You can then solve the $x, y$ and $z$ ODEs explicitly as well.

Comment: I have tried it but since z is also belonged to p and q, s and t so I could not get find solution.

Comment: But you know what $p$ and $q$ are in terms of $t$ from the ODEs in $p$ and $q$

$$p = A_{1}e^{-t}, \quad q = A_{2} e^{3t}$$

Now substitute these into the ODEs for $x, y$ and $z$, you just find that each ODE is inhomogeneous i.e

$$x' = 2x + 2A_{1}e^{-t} \implies (e^{-2t} x)' = 2A_{1}e^{-3t} \implies \dots$$

Comment: Thank for more hints but I still stuck

Answer (score 0):

Mattos' hints were pretty substantial. From the solutions to p and q, you can then solve for x, y, and z in terms of s & t. Using dy/dt and the strategies hinted above, one can solve for s in terms of y & t. Solving for t (or even exp(t)) in terms of x & y appears to be more difficult.